VSCode not recognising YAML-Package in Virtual Environment
I am using Python v3.12.5 in VSCode and with a virtual environment activated in a bash terminal:
(venv) 
User MINGW64 /c/code/venv_fork-main
$ conda list

# packages in environment at C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\envs\venv:
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
[other packages]          [...]                     [...]  [...]
yaml                      0.2.5                h8ffe710_2  conda-forge

However, it produces the error below:

yaml is installed in the environment. I originally installed it with conda-forge, but also tried anaconda:
yaml                   conda-forge::yaml-0.2.5-h8ffe710_2 --> anaconda::yaml-0.2.5-he774522_0

My interpreter is selected as 3.12.5 ('venv':conda).
I'm not sure if this is relevant to the issue, but I launch VSCode from Git Bash using
code .

as this has lead to positive experience in the past. However, recently it doesn't work and I get the following error:
(base)
User MINGW64 ~
$ code .
conda activate nexusnode:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1155
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Library\c\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\cli.js'
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1152:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:993:27)
    at c._load (node:electron/js2c/node_init:2:13801)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:189:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:28:49 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}

Only once I activate my venv:
conda activate venv
code .

does VSCode open.
I tried conda install conda as a method of resetting the base environment out of the chance that I installed packages in the base environment based on wjandrea's reference to Brett Cannon's answer.
Regardless of YAML not working/being recognised, all other packages are working without error.

Are you running the code in the environment? If you're running it in a different env, that could do it.

Have you already read this question? Why do I get a "ModuleNotFoundError" in VS Code despite the fact that I already installed the module? It's using pip, but some of the ideas are the same. I recommend Brett Cannon's answer first; he's one of the devs.

Thank you for your quick response @wjandrea. I updated the post accordingly. Do you have further recommendations or insight please?

Oh! I just realized you're using the wrong package. yaml is for C, pyyaml is for Python.

That solved it thank you - the solution is frustratingly simple. Can you post your comment as a response so that I can mark it as a solution?

You use the incorrect python package.
It should be pyyaml instaed of yaml.
